# In type problem in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, in-clause

My problem is i have source **www.yamaha.com** in my table but it was not picking up.
Please help me

```
SELECT * FROM linkbound_report_source l
 WHERE source in ('www.yamaha.com ,www.desmogblog.com ,www.cleantechnica.com ,www.thehill.com ,www.grist.org')
ORDER BY l.report_source_id desc
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You build the SQL dynamically? If so let us know what language and we'll help you build it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM linkbound_report_source l
 WHERE source in ('www.yamaha.com','www.desmogblog.com','www.cleantechnica.com','www.thehill.com','www.grist.org')
ORDER BY l.report_source_id desc
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote all separate string in IN statements :

```
SELECT * FROM linkbound_report_source l
WHERE source in ('www.yamaha.com' , 'www.desmogblog.com' ,'www.cleantechnica.com' ,'www.thehill.com'     ,'www.grist.org')
ORDER BY l.report_source_id desc
```

SQL `IN` syntax expects an enumeration of expressions. In your case several strings but in other case it can be numbers or dates.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html):

```
  bit_expr [NOT] IN (subquery)
| bit_expr [NOT] IN (expr [, expr] ...)
```